# where to put c# code to run on closing outlook

Tags: c#, events, interop, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook add-in and I want to run a couple of lines on closing
of Outlook, but I cannot find where to put the code.

I tested `ThisAddIn_Shutdown` and `Ribbon1_Unload` events, but the debugger
does not hit a breakpoint in either event.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: One way is:while digging I bumped on a help page that used explorer events but I do not know how to integrate that to my code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your current solution. How do you open Outlook? Do you use any events? etc

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the `ThisAddIn_Shutdown` event:

> The Shutdown event is raised only when the user disables the VSTO Add-in by using the COM Add-ins dialog box in Outlook. It is not raised when Outlook exits.

You want either the [`Quit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.quit) event of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` object or the [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorerevents_10_event.close) event of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer` object.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/events-in-office-projects?view=vs-2017#shutdown-event-in-outlook-vsto-add-ins) for more details.